# Punctuation: ";" vs ","

Tags: punctuation

> The telomere dysfunction is mainly manifested in liver in terms of
>   pathological aging, such as tolerated human liver allografts showed
>   accelerated telomere reduction and hepatocyte **senescence, telomere**
>   dysfunction promotes chronic liver diseases and hepatocarcinoma.

Which one should I use in here?
1)senescence, telomere
2)senescence; telomere

Thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty complex sentence! As I understand it, the bit before the comma/semi-colon does not have or require any connection to the bit after, or *vice versa*, so why not put a full stop and make it into a separate sentence?

Comment: What @JavaLatte said. But it looks to me as if the first "sentence" is actually more a *restatement* (with clarifying examples) of the second part. So it would seem far more natural to present them the other way round. *Telomere dysfunction promotes chronic liver diseases and hepatocarcinoma. The telomere dysfunction is mainly manifested in liver in terms of pathological aging, such as tolerated human liver allografts showing accelerated telomere reduction and hepatocyte senescence.* It's an ungainly sentence, not easy to parse, but I'm pretty sure it should be ***showing*** (not *showed*).

Comment: (And as an older Brit, I tend to prefer *is mainly **manifest***, but the past tense form has definitely gained the upper hand in AmE today.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have provided great suggestions, so I won't repeat them, but your paragraph is a bit out of whack grammar-wise and makes no sense as it is written. Consider rephrasing:

> Telomere dysfunction is primarily manifest(ed) in the liver in terms
>   of pathological aging. Tolerated human liver allografts have shown
>   accelerated telomere reduction and hepatocyte senescence, and telomere
>   dysfunction has been shown to promote chronic liver diseases and
>   hepatocarcinoma.

or

> Telomere dysfunction is mainly manifested in the liver in terms of
>   pathological aging, with tolerated human liver allografts showing
>   accelerated telomere reduction and hepatocyte senescence. Telomere
>   dysfunction has also been [linked to/shown to promote/proven to
>   promote] chronic liver diseases and hepatocarcinoma.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you don't want a comma or a semicolon. You need a period.

> ...telomere reduction and hepatocyte senescence. Telomere dysfunction promotes...

It should be two separate sentences because it expresses two separate ideas. The first is about teleomere dysfunction manifestation, while the second is about its effects on the body.